# Python – sum up/sort range of numbers from file

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, csv, formatting

This is my first post here, so sorry if I've done anything wrong, and I'll try to explain the best I can. I have two files, one a csv/txt file named **text1.txt** in the following format:

```
"13:02",10
"13:03",30
"13:04",15
"13:05",12
"13:06",3
```

…and another (plain text) file named **console1.txt** with something like this:

```
Rate limit: 5 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:00 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 5)
Rate limit: 10 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:01 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 15)
Rate limit: 17 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:06 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 32)
Rate limit: 10 at Thu Jun 12 13:05:50 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 42)
Rate limit: 14 at Thu Jun 12 13:05:53 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 56)
Rate limit: 84 at Thu Jun 12 13:05:21 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 140)
Rate limit: 2 at Thu Jun 12 13:06:30 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 142)
Rate limit: 5 at Thu Jun 12 13:06:34 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 147)
```

I want to sum up these numbers to get the total number "rate limited" each minute, and then add these to the corresponding rows in the first csv/txt file. So, the intended result will look like this:

```
"13:02",42
"13:03",30
"13:04",15
"13:05",120
"13:06",10
```

Numbers on lines with a timestamp beginning with *13:02* (so, 5 + 10 + 17 = 32 total) get summed up and added to the "13:02" column (32 + the original 10 = 42), that beginning with *13:05* gets added to the "13:05" column, and so on.

I'm not really sure how to approach *processing the data* – namely, summing up the numbers for each minute. Figuring out how to get the data from console.txt to a format such as

```
"13:02",32
"13:05",108
"13:06",7
```

would be helpful, and from there I could figure out how to add them to corresponding csv rows.

Thanks!

---

## EDIT:

Thinking through the process, here are my steps (with pseudo-code in curly brackets):

Let's say this is **console.txt**:

```
Rate limit: 5 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:00 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 5)
Rate limit: 10 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:01 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 15)
Rate limit: 5 at Thu Jun 12 13:06:34 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 20)
```

1) Reading in & cutting off all unnecessary data

```
temp = open("console.txt").read()
temp = temp2.replace("Rate limit: ", "")
temp = temp2.replace(" at Thu Jun 12 ", ",")
{{ Remove the text between "PDT 2014 (" and ")" including both of those string, i.e. cut off everything after the seconds marker starting at "PDT" – this I can do myself }}
{{ Cut off the seconds of each minute – *stuck here* }}
```

2) Formatting

```
{{ Add quotes around the times and reverse the two columns – can figure this out }}
```

This will get me:

```
"13:02",5
"13:02",10
"13:06",5
```

3) Saving to a new file

```py
file = open("file.txt", 'w')
file.write(temp)
file.close()
```

I can figure out adding the numbers to a similar csv file from this point.

Comment: What have *you* tried? Which part are you stuck on; parsing either or both of the files? Processing the data? Writing out the results? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Could you provide some code snippet of what you have got ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example (without reading and writing files):

```
csv = '''"13:02",10
"13:03",30
"13:04",15
"13:05",12
"13:06",3'''

rates = '''Rate limit: 5 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:00 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 5)
Rate limit: 10 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:01 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 15)
Rate limit: 17 at Thu Jun 12 13:02:06 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 32)
Rate limit: 10 at Thu Jun 12 13:05:50 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 42)
Rate limit: 14 at Thu Jun 12 13:05:53 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 56)
Rate limit: 84 at Thu Jun 12 13:05:21 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 140)
Rate limit: 2 at Thu Jun 12 13:06:30 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 142)
Rate limit: 5 at Thu Jun 12 13:06:34 PDT 2014 (Total missed: 147)'''

# --- example code ---

import re

all_times =  {}

# change csv into dict

for x in csv.splitlines():
    time, value  = x.split(',')
    all_times[time] = int(value)

# print dict

print '--- old ---' 
for k,v in all_times.items():
    print k, v

# add rates to dict

for x in rates.splitlines():
    value, time = re.findall('Rate limit: (\d+) .* (\d+:\d+):', x)[0]
    all_times['"%s"' % time] += int(value)

# print dict

print '--- new ---' 
for k,v in all_times.items():
    print k, v
```

Results:

```
--- old ---
"13:04" 15
"13:05" 12
"13:02" 10
"13:03" 30
"13:06" 3
--- new ---
"13:04" 15
"13:05" 120
"13:02" 42
"13:03" 30
"13:06" 10
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to approach this so I appreciate you sharing your method using dictionaries. I was able to build off of your code to achieve what I wanted. Thanks.